# Does a Dynatrace default configuration for BTP workload exist?

Tags: dynatrace, sap-business-technology-platform

We consume BTP services like XSUAA, Instance Manager and backing services.

Is there a set of Dynatrace default configuration available, to improve client side monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [BTP APM team](https://pages.github.tools.sap/apm/contact/) does provide a set of [default configuration](https://github.tools.sap/apm/dynatrace-configs). The default configuration can be applied using the [dt-cli](https://pages.github.tools.sap/apm/docs/automation/cli)

It will improve the detection of downstream services, and even add additional metadata, to improve troubleshooting and incident management.

Added metadata:

- Service Name
- [Service ID](https://services.tools.sap/)
- BTP Component

Furthermore services will track identityzone id's, with each request.